# Add class to <body> if url has /shop/

Tags: jquery, squarespace

I'm working on a SquareSpace shop and unfortunately for me, no class gets added to the body for all shop pages. By this I mean any page that starts with `http://example.com/shop/`

I would like to add a class to the body for all pages that start with this url whether it be `http://example.com/shop/item1`, `http://example.com/shop/category/category-name`, etc.

I tried this, but no class gets added to the `<body>`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(url.indexOf('/shop/') > -1){
        $("body").addClass("shop");
    }
});
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.href.match('example.com/shop')){
        $("body").addClass("shop");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Just curious, but is there a way to set a match for `example.com/shop/` and another for urls that have anything after the last backslash? For example, `example.com/shop/model-1` or `example.com/model-2`?

Comment: Yes of course, `match(/example\.com\/shop\/model-\d/)`
or `match(/example\.com\/shop\/model-[12]/)`

Comment: Thank you. However, not all urls will start with `model-` Is there a way to set a match for urls that have anything after `/shop/`? So it would match `example.com/shop/model-` or `example.com/shop/dsafdsafd` or `example.com/shop/item-` etc etc.?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `window.location.pathname` which is in your case `shop/index.html`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.pathname.match('shop')){
        $("body").addClass("shop");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use plain Javascript e.g

```
if (document.location.pathname.indexOf("/shop/") == 0) {
    document.body.className = "shop";
}
```

With `indexOf` it will return true for all pathnames starting with `/shop/`. And if so, it is adding the Class `shop` to the `<body>` Element.

So on every URL which starts with `shop` the `body` is getting an **ID** of `shop`.

Comment: Thanks for your Downvote. It will add the Class "shop" to the body with every URL which starts with /shop/. Thats what he wanted.